# in case of @DataJpaTest NoSuchBeanDefinitionException because of @Value

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, integration-testing

I tried to use only dataJpa layer for testing my repositories:

```
    @DataJpaTest
    @AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = NONE)
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @ActiveProfiles("test")
    public class DaoRepositoryTest extends                 AbstractTestWithPostgresContainer {

        private static final Logger log =         LoggerFactory.getLogger(DaoRepositoryTest.class);

        @Autowired
        private DaoRepository daoRepository;

        @Test
        @Sql("classpath:db/migration/V1.0__init.sql")
        public void save_shouldSave() {
            final Dao dao = Dao.builder()
                    .title("Test-title")
                    .build();

            final Dao result = daoRepository.save(orderDao);

            assertThat(result.getId()).isNotNull();
            log.info("Result: {}", result);
        }
    }
```

but I have ConfigurationProperties which I used in my app (I don't care of it in my repository test):

```
    @ConfigurationProperties("redirect-path")
    @Data
    public class PathProperties {
        private Map<String, String> paths;
    }
```

As a result, I have this exception:

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type application.config.RedirectPath' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

I think that it's because for DataJpaTest context doesn't use my property in yml :

```
    redirect-path:
      paths:
        test: http://localhost:8090
```

how can I tell a spring that I don't need to use PathProperties in my test?

Now I have to use the @SpringBootTest annotation.

Comment: How do you provide/use PathProperties into DaoRepository itself?

Comment: I don't use it into DaoRepository at all.